# Elasticsearch: How does filtered aliases work internally in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using filtered aliases in my project as mentioned in below link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-aliases.html#filtered
I want to understand how filtered aliases work internally?

Comment: It's a pretty broad question. What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Val !
So when we query on filtered aliases does ES maintains some cache in advance or does it scans the entire main index again and returns only the results matching the filter?
If it scans the main index everytime , how does it manage to return the results so fast.

Comment: Filters are [cached](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) by ES